# pygrametl CSVSource TypeError: init() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, csv, typeerror, pygrametl

I am trying to use pygrametl CSVSource as shown in the [documentation](https://chrthomsen.github.io/pygrametl/doc/examples/datasources.html#csvsource)

This is my code

```
import pygrametl
from pygrametl.datasources import CSVSource

src = CSVSource(csvfile=open('src.csv', 'r', 16384), \
                            delimiter=',')
```

but I get the following error even though I use the exact code.

> TypeError: **init**() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation You mentioned, we can see that `CSVSource` is just reference to `DictReader` from `csv` module.

If we look at the source code of `DictReader` class (it's `__init__` method, to be precise), we see this:

```
class DictReader:
     def __init__(self, f, fieldnames=None, restkey=None, restval=None,
                  dialect="excel", *args, **kwds):
         self._fieldnames = fieldnames   # list of keys for the dict
         self.restkey = restkey          # key to catch long rows
         self.restval = restval          # default value for short rows
         self.reader = reader(f, dialect, *args, **kwds)
         self.dialect = dialect
         self.line_num = 0
```

Since there is no keyword `csvfile` in the input arguments, this argument is passed to `**kwds`, meaning argument `f` is missing. I don't have this library installed, but I think that just passing `open('src.csv', 'r', 16384)` without `csvfile=` will fix this issue. Something like this:

```
import pygrametl
from pygrametl.datasources import CSVSource

src = CSVSource(open('src.csv', 'r', 16384), delimiter=',')
```

*Update*: Just installed `pygrametl` and tested without `csvfile=`, it works fine.